# Internal server error axis2 Tomcat service wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat7, apache-axis

I'm getting an Internal server error when try to see the wsdl from a service that I deployed in axis2.

Only the sample service of axis works "Version?wsdl".

Funny thing is that I'm able to see the xsd from my service, i.e "service?xsd", but not the wsdl.

Any ideas?

I'm using axis2-1.5.6 and Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: Try deploying axis2 on TomEE (plus) instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using https, you have to add following to your axis2.xml file

```
<transportReceiver name="https"
                   class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

([full article](http://dulanja.blogspot.de/2012/12/why-tomcat-gives-internal-server-error.html))

This enables https listeren for axis2. It is not enabled by default (unlike http access) .

the axis2.xml file can be found here:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml
```